# R: Apply function based on vector B to vector A

Tags: r

My first question...

I have two vectors, **q** and **n**. I want to perform a function on **q** based on the corresponding value in **n** (specifically *binom.test(q[t],n[t],0.5)*).

I've made a loop to do it, which works OK, but I'd like to know how to use apply functions to do it faster if such a thing is possible. I'm new to r, so please forgive my ignorance and probably sloppy formatting.

This is my loop:

```
q = ...
n = ... 
p = c()

for(t in c(1:30)) {p = c(p,binom.test(q[t],n[t],0.5)$p.value)}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `mapply`. Add some sample data for `q` and `n` and probably someone will show how to get that done.

Comment: Thanks to all for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `sapply` like this:

```
sapply(1:length(q), function(t) binom.test(q[t], n[t], 0.5)$p.value)
```